# datagridview counting specific data

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

In DataGridView (vb.net10) I want to be able to look for a specific piece of data
this could be a number or string.For the example lets take the string "sunshine".So in my column I want to count the number of times "sunshine" appears and then place this in a texbox.The problem is compounded by the fact that many of the columns have no data in them at all.(null).Is there a way I could loop through the column,account for the nulls and count the number of times a certain piece of data has appeared in the column(in this case sunshine) .I have managed to do this in vba,but cant crack it in vb.net.Any help appreciated
looknow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim itemCount as integer
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column").Value IsNot DBNull.Value or trim(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column").Value <> Nothing ) AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column").Value = "Sunshine" Then
      'your logic
       itemCount = itemCount + 1 
      End If
Next
```

---

By using [`LINQ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx)

```
Dim count = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows _
                  Where row.Cells("Your_Column_Name").Value = "Sunshine" And row.Cells("Your_Column_Name").Value IsNot DBNull.Value _
                  Select row.Cells("Your_Column_Name").Value).Count()
```

I recommend LINQ because it's more better than Looping method

Comment: you should check for `DBNull.Value` or `Nothing` first and use `AndAlso` instead of `And`

Comment: Hi vivek,thankyou for the reply.I keep getting the blue squigly lines beneath dgv_events..I tried changing this to DataGridView1_events(which is my datagrid but it is still the sam...the message reads..'dgv_ events' not declared.It may be inaccesible due to its protection level.Any suggestions much appreciated.Looknow

Comment: `dgv_events` is the name of my datagridview replace it with your datagridview

Comment: use `DataGridView1` instead of `DataGridView1_events`

Comment: Check my update I've included an easier method to get the count

Comment: Hi Vivek,Thanks for your reply,that got rid of the blue lines and the  program runs but I now get the following message up:Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid...Could this be becuase of integer and string types.Regards Looknow

Comment: @looknow BTW, which method are you using ?

Comment: Hi Vivek..Great that Linq worked fine many thanks for your help,much appreciated.regrads looknow